# Is it really faster to select by position than by name in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I work in a company that reinvented the wheel in almost any way possible (and the result is a square wheel or something worse). One of the things they did was to create a framework for web development (based on the Visual Basic 6.0 model of "events"... yes, my life sucks).

It's impossible to let them understand the many bad decisions they took, they (the boss and all "the old ones"), are more stubborn that a mule and always justified everthing with lame arguments, being always the final "performance".

One of the things they did that intrigue me is a Persistor layer that read every select by position; so, if I have to add a field to a table, I have to update like 20 places because all is hardcoded (one architect that resigned on frustration suggested at least use  some kind of enumeration but no: "Performance!!".

So, my question is: there is any base to the argument that, in SQL Server at least, a `Select 1, 2, 3 from Table` is faster than `Select Field1, Field2. Field3 from table`?

Comment: I'd suggest quitting.

Comment: FASTER: it can quickly lead to errors and problems.

Comment: Sounds like they started database design 30 years ago and didn't learn since then. I can remember that in the late 1980s, it was indeed a performance gain to use `select 1,2,3` with oracle, dbase, gupta, etc. But forget about that in current sql server implementations. Today, sql server has a wonderful optimiziation engine, and such a statement is total peanuts for the sql server.

Comment: The question is not really clear. `SELECT 1, 2, 3 from Table` will return constants `1`, `2`, `3`, but `SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3 from Table` will return values of these columns. How does your actual SQL query look like? It seems that the question is not about SQL Server, but about some data-access library.

Answer (score 1):

**LE 2:**

`SELECT 1, 2, 3, 4 FROM Table` **won't select you the actual data or columns from the table.**

As from an execution plan it doesn't look like `SELECT 1, 2, 3 FROM Table` is faster[image]

Also you may consider, that running the query as `SELECT 1, 2, 3 FROM Table` will return columns with (No column name) and also it's not very wise to do so, in case the columns order change.

LE : This was a query with over 200.000 records and with only 3 columns.

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: Have you checked what your select brings back? I'm seeing 1, 2 and 3 (these numbers) in result set, not actual data.

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas you are right, did not even look at that, i was looking only at the execution plan. I don't even think is possible to USE SELEC 1, 2 FROM TABLE

Comment: Possible. However only using Dynamic SQL.

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas could be, but I don't think it will do any good in terms of being faster.

Comment: There is **for sure** no difference. SQL Server today has an incredibly wonderful optimization engine, and you almost have no chance today to optimize even big and complex queries with hints and other tricks. But as I said above, I can indeed remember that something like 'select 1,2,3' was a performance gain in the late 1980s.